# Equivalence of defining the Fenchel conjugate as $\sup_x\{\langle x^*, x \rangle - f(x)\}$ or $\inf_x\{f(x)-\langle x^*, x \rangle\}$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, duality-theorems

The canonical definition of Fenchel conjugate function is that for a function $f(x)$, $$f^*(x^*) = \textsf{sup}_{x}\{\langle x^*, x \rangle - f(x)\}$$
which is equivalent to $f^*(x^*) =-\textsf{inf}_x\{f(x)-\langle x^*, x \rangle\}$. Recently as I was reading *Optimization by vector space methods*, I noticed that in Section 8.6, in order to prove the Lagrange duality theorem, the book introduces another dual functional: 
$$\textsf{inf}_{x}\{f(x)+ \langle x^*, x\rangle\}$$
 The book claims that those two definitions are essentially the same. I can see that they have the same geometric interpretation, but I failed to prove that they are the same rigorously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define
$$f^*(y) = \textsf{sup}_{x}\{\langle x, y\rangle - f(x)\}$$
$$g(y) = \textsf{inf}_{x}\{f(x)+ \langle x, y\rangle\},$$
then $f^*(y) = -g(-y)$.